# Basic if, else, and elseif functions.

Tags: vb.net

So im trying to use if, else, and else if to decide if a player makes the team or not. For example they have to be equal to 74 inches or greater and equal to 210 pounds or greater to make the team.

Heres the kicker I can get it to say they "Made the team" with both the Height and Weight. And I can get it to say "You did not make the team" when you input the weight below 210 pounds. However if the weight is kept at 210 and the height is input wrong it will still say he made the team.

I was wondering what im doing wrong? I cant seem to figure out were to put the correct "if" and "else" can someone explain to me what im doing wrong?

```
Read(_name, Height, Weight)     
If (Height >= 74) Then
        If (Weight >= 210) Then
            Print("Welcome New Pats Player!")
        Else : Print("You did not make the team")
        End If
    End If



    Write(Height)
    Write(Weight)
    Write(_name)

Print()
Print("By Chuck")
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know vb.net, but you might want to try:

```
If (Height >= 74 And Weight >=210) Then

    Print("Welcome New Pats Player!")

Else : Print("You did not make the team")

End If
```

Comment: Negative it gives me the same outcome. As the answer below and mine above.

Comment: @Lhant21 `Negative it gives me the same outcome` means what i can't understand. i think the answer is correct

Comment: @SATSON I'm confused too!!

Comment: @SATSON this is not my question... I was the one who answer another one.

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years ok Ok.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?     Add another Else Clause

```
 If (Height >= 74) Then
    If (Weight >= 210) Then
        Print("Welcome New Pats Player!")
    Else : Print("You did not make the team")
    End If
 Else : Print("You did not make the team")
 End If
```

Comment: Negative it gives me the same outcome.